# Getting an Error in Rails Model Test - Expected "3" Actual 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

I've got this test in my Rails app's test/models folder:

```
  test "has quantity" do
    @i.quantity = 3
    assert_equal @i.quantity, 3
  end
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Expected: "3"
Actual: 3
```

I'm setting the value as an integer (and the database column is set to integer). Here's the corresponding migration:

```
class AddQuantityToItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :items, :quantity, :integer
  end
end
```

If I set the test to:

```
  test "has quantity" do
    @i.quantity = 3
    assert_equal @i.quantity, "3"
  end
```

The error goes away. Should I just do this or is there a way to make the value an integer instead of a string? (or does this even matter in Ruby?)

Any ideas are appreciated.

Thanks for you time.

Comment: What's the Ruby/Rails version? What's the DB and version you are using? How is the object created in the test?

Comment: Rails 4.2.0, pg 9.4. - ended up solving the problem by reloading my test database. Originally had the object set as a string so when the db reloaded my changes were there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I just do this

No.  :)  Because your test is detecting that something is amiss.

> Or is there a way to make the value an integer instead of a string?

Ruby numbers have a method `to_i`, for example `"3".to_i #=> 3`

> Does this even matter in Ruby?

Yes, it matters. Ruby treats numbers and strings differently.

You can see Ruby uses different classes:

```
3.class #=> Fixnum
"3".class #=> String
```

And the values are not equal:

```
3 == "3" #=> false
```

Can you try some diagnostics? What do you get when you do these...

```
item = Item.new
puts item.quantity.class
item.quantity = 3
puts item.quantity.class
```

And these...

```
test "has quantity" do
  puts @i.class
  puts @i.quantity.class
  @i.quantity = 3
  puts @i.quantity.class
  assert_equal @i.quantity, 3
end
```

And in your database, can you print the test database table schema?

MySQL example:

```
desc items
```

My guess is your schema in the test database is not what you expect.

In general, you may want to try eliminating the `@i` from your test, because the `@` sign means that `@i` is an instance variable coming from somewhere beyond that particular test.

For example:

```
test "has quantity" do
  i = Item.new
  i.quantity = 3
  assert_equal i.quantity, 3
end
```

Comment: Thanks Joel. I ended up adding another test and the error went away. I think I just needed to reset my testing data because I initially had the value set as a string. Got it solved now though - thanks for the thorough answer!